# Find Hadoop folder where file count is exact 1 or 0

Tags: linux, hadoop, hdfs

I am looking for a Hadoop command to find folders where the file count is exactly 1 or 0.

I have tried

```
hdfs dfs -count <path>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this cmd:

```
hdfs dfs -count -q /path/file
```

Comment: If might be useful to point out what the `-q` parameter does, and why you believe adding that parameter will solve the problem. Keep in mind, they already tried `hdfs dfs -count`.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is any direct comand
This would lead you to have more files, so you will have to do directory wise

```
hdfs dfs -ls -R /*/* > get_file_list
grep "^d" get_file_list > get_directory_list
sort get_directory_list|uniq -c |grep "1 "
```

This will at least give you directories which has 1 or 0 files
now you can run du on the list of directories you got..